# Unable to use sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, centos-7, sudoers

I'm connecting via SSH to a Centos 7 machine. I have a user that cannot perform any command as super user. If I do:

```
$ sudo ls /
```

I get the error: "sudo: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable".
The user is a member both of the sudo and the admin groups. When I enter the groups command, I get: "myuser sudo admin", and my /etc/sudoers file has the lines:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So what could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing some kind of resource limitation. [This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205016/198222) could help you.

Try

```
ulimit -Sn unlimited && ulimit -Sl unlimited
```

Comment: @Worthwelle hope this is better